# How do software updates not wipe all user data & settings

Tags: vb.net, winforms, upgrade, patch

Please reference [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748586/i-dont-get-how-a-program-can-update-itself-how-can-i-make-my-software-update) to see where I am coming from.

I understand how the *.exe files are overwritten in an update. but how is code setup so that users themes, file save locations, database connections, are saved & reloaded.

I wrote a simple ticketing software in VB code & WinForms a while back. (basically how google forms works write to gsheets/excel file. I now wish to deploy an update to that system with some project management tools integrated. (timeline / gantt charts). In my first software all of those settings & paths are just saved as variables & then set as defaults. If I overwrite that *.exe file how will the software know what settings to use?

Is it possible to have my new update scan and import those variables from my old file? Or am I just out of luck? If I am out of luck what do I need to do to prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

I have not made any attempts to update the program yet as it has too much data that I can't effectively back up (another problem in the works)

Comment: User data is not part of the exe but external files which are not part of an update, simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

User settings, such as theme settings, configuration options, and the like, are stored in *configuration files* that are external to the application. These files are usually saved in either the user's roaming profile, or in a subfolder of the user's My Documents folder (or its corollary on Linux or Mac).

When the application is updated, these configuration files remain largely untouched. (New options usually have a reasonable default value.)